# Is there a more efficent way to iter over every character of a sring using it's index?

Tags: python

I was trying to match two strings together using the for loop and had to use the range(len(my_string)) functions to iter over its indexes.

Here is my code:

```
my_string = 'something'
key = 'something else'
for i in range(len(my_string)):
    if my_string[i] == key[i]:
        # do something
```

I was wondering if there's a better or more efficient way to iter over indexes without using the len() and range() functions, perhaps treating the string as a list.

something like this (I know it's not correct):

```
for i in my_string:
    if my_string[i] == key[i]:
        # rest of the code
```

Comment: Unless you need the index for some other reason, you could use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: just to `my_string == key`

Comment: take a look at `enumerate`

Comment: Is `my_list` a typo or are you iterating over the length of some other variable?

Comment: What output are you trying to get? what do you expect to happen with the additional characters in the longer string?

Comment: You said something about "treating the string as a list", so I'd just like to point out that a string is already iterable. `for c in strval` works, but it gets you only the characters, not the indexes, just like `for el in listval` does. Use `enumerate` to get the indexes, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to need the index at all, so just [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them:

```
for m, k in zip(my_string, key):
    if m == k:
        # rest of the code
```

If you need the index, [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) works:

```
for i, m in enumerate(my_string):
    if m == key[i]:
        # rest of the code
```

and can be combined with `zip`:

```
for i, (m, k) in enumerate(zip(my_string, key)):
    if m == k:
        # rest of the code
```

Comment: Notice that zip stops when the shorter of the two lists is over. This might not be what you want here.

Comment: @VladKeel: True, but in this particular case, they're checking if the values match and only doing something if they do. "Existing character" and "non-existing character" definitely don't match. `itertools.zip_longest` (or using `itertools.cycle` to stretch one of the values forever, which makes sense in some "key" scenarios) can be used when it's not appropriate.